# Add only one selection out of group to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm creating a football betting app, where I'd like to pick a winner/loser/draw from a match, and then store that in a list of selected bets.

[image]

#### What I have so far

For each match, you can select a winner of either team or a draw. The `getSelection` method is passed down as props to the `onClick` handler of each button.

The `getSelection` method then adds the value of the button click to an array, like so:

```
getSelection = (val: object) => {
    this.setState(
        {bets: [...this.state.bets, val]},
        () => console.log(this.state.bets, "bets")
    );
};
```

I want only to be able to make a single selection for each match, represented visually like so:

[Codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/rw8plm490q?fontsize=14)

[image]

Comment: Please show us the output, array/object something.

Comment: Hi Dhaval thanks for commenting. The output is printed to the console in the Sandbox whenever you click a button?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, your desired output, what you're looking for. I saw everytime on click the selection gets added into the array. But still unsure about what output you need.

Comment: Ah, apologies! I'm finding it hard to articulate this. So basically, out of each match, you should be able to pick a winner, or a draw. Currently it keeps adding selections to the array, so it only gets bigger. But say if there's two matches and a user has selected a winner for both, it should only ever be an array of 2 objects. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please check the edit I made in the question.

Comment: Note that you can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) to include all of the relevant code here on Stack Overflow instead of making users go to a different site. Also, we want future users to be able to understand the question and answer, and if that link goes stale, this question won't be as easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is updating the Match Results based on the User's selection.

**SINGLE MATCH WILL HAVE SINGLE RESULT, i.e RESULTS WILL OVERWRITE**

Also to keep track of Match Number, I have used `matchNumber` as an index.

Your `getSelection` will look something like this.

```
getSelection = (val: object, matchNumber: number) => {
    // 1. Make a shallow copy of the items
    let bets = [...this.state.bets];
    // 2. Make a shallow copy of the item you want to mutate
    let bet = { ...bets[matchNumber] };
    // 3. Replace the property you're intested in
    bet = val;
    // 4. Put it back into our array. N.B. we *are* mutating the array here, but that's why we made a copy first
    bets[matchNumber] = bet;
    // 5. Set the state to our new copy
    this.setState({ bets }, () => console.log(this.state.bets));
```

**Update the background:**

```
<button
    style={{ background: winner == home.name ? "lightblue" : "white" }}
    onClick={() => this.props.getSelection(home, matchNumber)}
  >
    {home.name}
  </button>
  <button
    style={{ background: winner == draw.name ? "lightblue" : "white" }}
    onClick={() => this.props.getSelection(draw, matchNumber)}
  >
    {draw.name}
  </button>
  <button
    style={{ background: winner == away.name ? "lightblue" : "white" }}
    onClick={() => this.props.getSelection(away, matchNumber)}
  >
    {away.name}
  </button>
```

Check this working solution. https://codesandbox.io/s/9lpnvx188y

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience, sir! This works perfectly. Just going through the code now, trying to wrap my head around it. Thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem Sir, do let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you should only be able to add a single possibility once?
Then this might work:

```
    getSelection = (val: object) => {
      this.setState( {
        bets: [...this.state.bets, val].filter((value, index, self) => { return self.indexOf(value) === index; })
        },
        () => console.log(this.state.bets, "bets")
      );
    };
```

(That is, take the entire array, add the new value, filter so you only get the distinct values, and store it in bets).

ala: https://codesandbox.io/s/x2o5m95oxw

Comment: Hey @devjc thanks for posting. Yes, I'd like to be able to add a single selection from each match, and your example is *almost* there, but your example will keep adding more than 2 to the array. I've updated the original post to visually represent what I want to happen.